# Does anyone know how to fix Maven's Compilation issue?

Tags: java, xml, maven

So I am currently working on a multi-module project. I have worked on this project for almost a year and everything has been working fine up until recently. Everything has been able to compile except for the important piece, which is my libraries module called "Bookstore". Bookstore was compiling about a couple of days ago until IntelliJ had some updates and I went to update. Now when I go to compile my plugin I get a fat "Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:compile (default-compile) on project Bookstore: Compilation failure An unknown compilation problem occurred". Please help. I have tried everything. I have reinstalled java 8 and 9 JDK, added more memory, even added in the typical maven-plugin dependency to make it work. Nothing works this is how my pom looks:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>net.conquestmc</groupId>
        <artifactId>conquest-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0C-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <groupId>net.conquestmc.bookstore</groupId>
    <artifactId>Bookstore</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>Bookstore</name>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <defaultGoal>clean install</defaultGoal>
        <finalName>${project.name}-${conquestversion}</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <createDependencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>pl.project13.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>git-commit-id-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>4.0.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>get-the-git-infos</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>revision</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>initialize</phase>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <generateGitPropertiesFile>false</generateGitPropertiesFile>
                    <dateFormat>dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss</dateFormat>
                    <verbose>true</verbose>
                    <dotGitDirectory>${project.parent.basedir}/.git</dotGitDirectory>
                    <offline>true</offline>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>
</project>
```

And if you guys need the stack-trace of whats being sent here it is:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\bin\java.exe" "-Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=C:\Users\babyboy1\Desktop\IntelliJ Projects\MC Repositories\conquest-parent\Bookstore" "-Dmaven.home=S:\Development\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.1.1\plugins\maven\lib\maven3" "-Dclassworlds.conf=S:\Development\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.1.1\plugins\maven\lib\maven3\bin\m2.conf" "-Dmaven.ext.class.path=S:\Development\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.1.1\plugins\maven\lib\maven-event-listener.jar" "-javaagent:S:\Development\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.1.1\lib\idea_rt.jar=63088:S:\Development\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.1.1\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "S:\Development\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.1.1\plugins\maven\lib\maven3\boot\plexus-classworlds-2.6.0.jar;S:\Development\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.1.1\plugins\maven\lib\maven3\boot\plexus-classworlds.license" org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher -Didea.version2020.1.2 --errors --update-snapshots -s "S:\.m2 - ssd\.m2\settings.xml" "-Dmaven.repo.local=S:\.m2 - ssd\.m2\repository" clean install
[INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] -----------------< net.conquestmc.bookstore:Bookstore >-----------------
[INFO] Building Bookstore 1.0.0C-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
Downloading from sonatype: https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public/org/spigotmc/mcspigot/1.15.2-R0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading from spigotmc-public: https://hub.spigotmc.org/nexus/content/groups/public/org/spigotmc/spigot-parent/dev-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading from sonatype: https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public/org/spigotmc/spigot-parent/dev-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading from sonatype: https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public/org/spigotmc/mcspigot-api/1.15.2-R0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading from sonatype: https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public/net/md-5/bungeecord-chat/1.15-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading from spigotmc-public: https://hub.spigotmc.org/nexus/content/groups/public/net/md-5/bungeecord-chat/1.15-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
Downloaded from spigotmc-public: https://hub.spigotmc.org/nexus/content/groups/public/net/md-5/bungeecord-chat/1.15-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml (1.2 kB at 4.6 kB/s)
Downloaded from sonatype: https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public/net/md-5/bungeecord-chat/1.15-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml (1.2 kB at 4.2 kB/s)
Downloading from sonatype: https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public/net/md-5/bungeecord-parent/1.15-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading from spigotmc-public: https://hub.spigotmc.org/nexus/content/groups/public/net/md-5/bungeecord-parent/1.15-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
Downloaded from sonatype: https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public/net/md-5/bungeecord-parent/1.15-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml (602 B at 5.0 kB/s)
Downloaded from spigotmc-public: https://hub.spigotmc.org/nexus/content/groups/public/net/md-5/bungeecord-parent/1.15-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml (602 B at 3.9 kB/s)
Downloading from sonatype: https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public/net/md-5/bungeecord-api/1.14-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
Downloaded from sonatype: https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public/net/md-5/bungeecord-api/1.14-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml (1.2 kB at 9.8 kB/s)
Downloading from sonatype: https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public/net/md-5/bungeecord-parent/1.14-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
Downloaded from sonatype: https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public/net/md-5/bungeecord-parent/1.14-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml (602 B at 5.1 kB/s)
Downloading from sonatype: https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public/net/md-5/bungeecord-chat/1.14-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
Downloaded from sonatype: https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public/net/md-5/bungeecord-chat/1.14-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml (1.2 kB at 10 kB/s)
Downloading from sonatype: https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public/net/md-5/bungeecord-config/1.14-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
Downloaded from sonatype: https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public/net/md-5/bungeecord-config/1.14-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml (1.2 kB at 10 kB/s)
Downloading from sonatype: https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public/net/md-5/bungeecord-event/1.14-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
Downloaded from sonatype: https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public/net/md-5/bungeecord-event/1.14-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml (1.2 kB at 9.4 kB/s)
Downloading from sonatype: https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public/net/md-5/bungeecord-protocol/1.14-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
Downloaded from sonatype: https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public/net/md-5/bungeecord-protocol/1.14-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml (1.2 kB at 9.7 kB/s)
Downloading from sonatype: https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public/net/md-5/brigadier/1.0.16-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading from sonatype-nexus-snapshots: https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/net/md-5/brigadier/1.0.16-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
Downloaded from sonatype: https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public/net/md-5/brigadier/1.0.16-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml (1.2 kB at 8.8 kB/s)
Downloaded from sonatype-nexus-snapshots: https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/net/md-5/brigadier/1.0.16-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml (1.2 kB at 4.1 kB/s)
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ Bookstore ---
[INFO] Deleting C:\Users\babyboy1\Desktop\IntelliJ Projects\MC Repositories\conquest-parent\Bookstore\target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- git-commit-id-plugin:4.0.0:revision (get-the-git-infos) @ Bookstore ---
[INFO] dotGitDirectory C:\Users\babyboy1\Desktop\IntelliJ Projects\MC Repositories\conquest-parent\.git
[INFO] Collected git.build.user.name with value babyboy1
[INFO] Collected git.build.user.email with value jordang774@gmail.com
[INFO] Collected git.branch with value development
[INFO] --always = true
[INFO] --dirty = -dirty
[INFO] --abbrev = 7
[INFO] Tag refs [[]]
[INFO] Created map: [{}]
[INFO] evalCommit is [d7a89b4a68b0ff74f20fb40068611f4fd3b8c994]
[INFO] Collected git.commit.id.describe with value d7a89b4-dirty
[INFO] Collected git.commit.id.describe-short with value d7a89b4-dirty
[INFO] Collected git.commit.id with value d7a89b4a68b0ff74f20fb40068611f4fd3b8c994
[INFO] Collected git.commit.id.abbrev with value d7a89b4
[INFO] Collected git.dirty with value true
[INFO] Collected git.commit.user.name with value babyboy1
[INFO] Collected git.commit.user.email with value jordang774@gmail.com
[INFO] Collected git.commit.message.full with value - Added NMSReflectionTool class for dynamically using NMS/OBC packages to get retrieve data.
[INFO] Collected git.commit.message.short with value - Added NMSReflectionTool class for dynamically using NMS/OBC packages to get retrieve data.
[INFO] Collected git.commit.time with value 07.06.2020 22:57:16
[INFO] Collected git.remote.origin.url with value https://babyboy1@gitlab.com/conquest-network/conquest-parent.git
[INFO] Collected git.tags with value 
[INFO] evalCommit is [d7a89b4a68b0ff74f20fb40068611f4fd3b8c994]
[INFO] Tag refs [[]]
[INFO] Created map: [{}]
[INFO] Collected git.closest.tag.name with value 
[INFO] evalCommit is [d7a89b4a68b0ff74f20fb40068611f4fd3b8c994]
[INFO] Tag refs [[]]
[INFO] Created map: [{}]
[INFO] Collected git.closest.tag.commit.count with value 
[INFO] Collected git.total.commit.count with value 21
[INFO] Collected git.local.branch.ahead with value 0
[INFO] Collected git.local.branch.behind with value 0
[INFO] Collected git.build.time with value 14.06.2020 22:52:23
[INFO] Collected git.build.version with value 1.0.0C-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] Collected git.build.host with value DESKTOP-I2F2616
[INFO] including property git.build.user.email in results
[INFO] including property git.build.host in results
[INFO] including property git.dirty in results
[INFO] including property git.local.branch.behind in results
[INFO] including property git.remote.origin.url in results
[INFO] including property git.closest.tag.name in results
[INFO] including property git.local.branch.ahead in results
[INFO] including property git.total.commit.count in results
[INFO] including property git.commit.id.describe-short in results
[INFO] including property git.commit.user.email in results
[INFO] including property git.commit.time in results
[INFO] including property git.commit.message.full in results
[INFO] including property git.build.version in results
[INFO] including property git.commit.message.short in results
[INFO] including property git.commit.id.abbrev in results
[INFO] including property git.branch in results
[INFO] including property git.build.user.name in results
[INFO] including property git.closest.tag.commit.count in results
[INFO] including property git.commit.id.describe in results
[INFO] including property git.commit.id in results
[INFO] including property git.tags in results
[INFO] including property git.build.time in results
[INFO] including property git.commit.user.name in results
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ Bookstore ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 4 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:compile (default-compile) @ Bookstore ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 59 source files to C:\Users\babyboy1\Desktop\IntelliJ Projects\MC Repositories\conquest-parent\Bookstore\target\classes
An exception has occurred in the compiler (1.8.0_181). Please file a bug against the Java compiler via the Java bug reporting page (http://bugreport.java.com) after checking the Bug Database (http://bugs.java.com) for duplicates. Include your program and the following diagnostic in your report. Thank you.
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/objectweb/asm/commons/JSRInlinerAdapter
    at lombok.bytecode.AsmUtil.fixJSRInlining(AsmUtil.java:40)
    at lombok.bytecode.SneakyThrowsRemover.applyTransformations(SneakyThrowsRemover.java:46)
    at lombok.core.PostCompiler.applyTransformations(PostCompiler.java:43)
    at lombok.core.PostCompiler$1.close(PostCompiler.java:76)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.jvm.ClassWriter.writeClass(ClassWriter.java:1629)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.genCode(JavaCompiler.java:746)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.generate(JavaCompiler.java:1572)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.generate(JavaCompiler.java:1536)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.compile2(JavaCompiler.java:901)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.compile(JavaCompiler.java:860)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:523)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.doCall(JavacTaskImpl.java:129)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.call(JavacTaskImpl.java:138)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.javac.JavaxToolsCompiler.compileInProcess(JavaxToolsCompiler.java:126)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.javac.JavacCompiler.performCompile(JavacCompiler.java:174)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute(AbstractCompilerMojo.java:1075)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilerMojo.execute(CompilerMojo.java:168)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:193)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:347)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:47)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.objectweb.asm.commons.JSRInlinerAdapter
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:530)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at lombok.launch.ShadowClassLoader.loadClass(ShadowClassLoader.java:534)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 40 more
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] An unknown compilation problem occurred
[INFO] 1 error
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  10.641 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-06-14T22:52:27-04:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:compile (default-compile) on project Bookstore: Compilation failure
[ERROR] An unknown compilation problem occurred
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:compile (default-compile) on project Bookstore: Compilation failure
An unknown compilation problem occurred

    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:47)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilationFailureException: Compilation failure
An unknown compilation problem occurred

    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute (AbstractCompilerMojo.java:1161)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilerMojo.execute (CompilerMojo.java:168)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:47)
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

Comment: Had better add some snapshots to give us more info about it

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Looks like you are missing some jar, due to which you are getting class not found an error.

Try adding following dependency

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.ow2.asm/asm-commons -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.ow2.asm</groupId>
    <artifactId>asm-commons</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.3</version>
</dependency>
```

And, try googling some things around it, if it doesn't work. Most probably it will work.